# Method attributes in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

What is the best way to assign security logic to a method in ASP.NET WebForms? Where instead of checking under each method if the user is logged in, can't we use method attributes?
Example, instead of doing this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (!UserLoggedIn)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/login");
        }
        //Do stuff
    }
```

I would like to do something like below. I've seen it done in ASP.NET MVC apps but I wonder if I can pull it off with webforms. And also what would be the best practice for ensuring only an authenticated user can continue and others get redirected to login page?

Ex: Desired. Where Secure is a method attribute:

```
[Secure]
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //Do stuff
    }
```

How do I go about creating such method attribute? And if that is not possible, how would you recommend I do it? I have many usercontrols that need this on page_load or oninit and I am looking for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SecureAttribute: Attribute
{             
}
```

Create custom base page class for all forms

```
public class PageBase: Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        var secureAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof (SecureAttribute));
        if (secureAttr != null)
        {
            bool UserLoggedIn = false; // get actual state from DB or Session

            if (!UserLoggedIn)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inherit all your forms from the PageBase

```
[Secure]
public partial class Profile: PageBase
{

}
```

Create similar UserControlBase for user controls.

Comment: Thanks, this great! But instead of attributing the whole class is there a way to only attribute a method? Ex: let Page_Load be viewable without authentication but ensure Button_submit redirects to login page if there is no authentication session?

Comment: Plz, see my second answer

Answer (score 1):

One possible Solution would be a PageBase helper class to avoid check that condition on every single pages on your ASP.NET web forms and just inherits the page-base in your aspx.cs classes. something like the code below:

for example you want to make sure that some web forms are only accessible by Admin users then you could have a AdminPageBase class to check this condition for all of your web pages.

your base class:

> ```
> public class AdminPageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
> {
>
>     protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||
>             !HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(Roles.Admin.ToString()))
>         {
>             this.RedirectToLogin();
>         }
>     }
>
>     protected void RedirectToLogin()
>     {
>         //...
>
>         Response.Redirect("~/SignIn.aspx");
>     }
> }
> ```

Note: *Roles.Admin.ToString()* is an enum, but you can also use a plain string if you like

and in your web form classes you only inherits this base class like this:

e.g. AdminPage1.aspx.cs

> ```
> public partial class AdminPage1: AdminPageBase
> {
>     //....
> }
> ```

e.g. AdminPage2.aspx.cs

> ```
> public partial class AdminPage2: AdminPageBase
> {
>     //....
> }
> ```
>
> and you could always do the same for all other pages in your solution.
>   you could also change Page_Init to Page_Load on your PageBase class but the reason I have chosen the Page_Init is because you may need Page_Load event to check other things on your page so it's a good place to check your website security.

Answer (score 1):

In order to intercept method calls, I would recommend utilizing some AOP framework, e.g. PostSharp, which allows easily inject behaviors before and after method execution by declaring custom aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class SecureAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        bool UserLoggedIn = false; // get from DB

        if (!UserLoggedIn)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

And applying that attribute to any method

```
public partial class Profile : Page
{

    [Secure]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [Secure]
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

As far as I know, PostSharp incures minor performance hit, or incures no performance hit at all,  as PostSharp emits MSIL instructions.